# I am trying to make a custom pow() function but my for loops are not working - C

Tags: c, for-loop, pow

I am trying to make a custom pow() function to compare the results of an actual pow function, but it is not working. When the base is 1 it works fine but after that MyPower function will return 1 for anything to the first power, so it will say.

Testing 1.000000 to the 1 power
Testing 1.000000 to the 2 power
Testing 1.000000 to the 3 power
Testing 1.000000 to the 4 power
2.000000 to the 1 is 2.000000, result is 1.000000
2.000000 to the 2 is 4.000000, result is 2.000000
2.000000 to the 3 is 8.000000, result is 4.000000
2.000000 to the 4 is 16.000000, result is 8.000000

and it will go on to be on one exponent value less for all the rest of the bases. I believe the error is occurring in the MyPower() function but I am not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double base, x;
int exponent, i, z;

double MyPower(double base, int exponent);
void DoTest(double base, int exponent);


double MyPower(double base, int exponent){
    double x = 1;
    for(z = 1; z < exponent; z++){
        x *= base;
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < 5; j++){
            DoTest(i,j);
        }
    }
}


void DoTest(double base, int exponent){
    double test1 = MyPower(base, exponent);
    double pow_result = pow(base, exponent);
    if(test1 == pow_result){
        printf("Testing %f to the %d power\n", base, exponent);
    }
    else{
        printf("%f to the %d is %f, result is %f\n", base, exponent, pow_result, test1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `z <= exponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem comes from the condition in your loop.**

The combination of the initial value you give to z and the exit condition makes it go through one iteration less than what you want to do:

```
for(z = 1; z < exponent; z++){
    x *= base;
}
```

You need to change it to either:

```
for(z = 0; z < exponent; z++){
```

or:

```
for(z = 1; z <= exponent; z++){
```

**A little piece of advice when debugging programs**

It may seem old-fashioned, but trying to run your algorithms with pen and paper will help you detect these kind of mistakes. No doubt your will become more and more proficient as you get more experienced. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for such a simple typo I think we should be voting to close this as "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."